# What is wrong with this code in C programming language?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When compiled no compilation errors but force closes when taken input. Do i have to use double pointer? help me out please. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int *a;
    allocate(a);
    input(a);
    display(a);
}
void allocate(int *a){
    a = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
}

void input(int *a){
    int i=0;
    for(;i<3;i++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
}
void display(int *a){
    int i=0;
    for(; i<3;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The value returned by `malloc` is lost once you exit the `allocate` function.

Comment: One problem right off: your `allocate` function won't return the address in `a`. The argument `a` is local to the function. You need to pass `int **a` then assign `*a = malloc(sizeof(int)*3)` and call it with `allocate(&a)` from `main`. Or just make it a return value `int *allocate(void) { return malloc(sizeof(int)*3); }`.

Comment: @lurker 
I get the output as you suggested but i didn't understand why it didn't worked before can you explain more.. Please thanks.